# Install AIDE in Slackware in 14.2

Tags: linux, package-management, slackware, installation-package

I want to install aide in slackware but the package manager cannot download aide package. I tried the code below with no luck :

```
slackpkg install aide
```

The output shows :

```
Looking for aide in package list. Please wait . . . Done

No packages match the pattern or install. Try

/usr/sbin/slackpkg reinstall|upgrade
```

How will I fixt it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to download the package from

```
https://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.2/system/aide/
```

and install it with `installpkg`.

Comment: Thank you sir. Is there a command where I can automatically download a file from a certain link? or do I have to do it in other computer and just pass thorught file transfer via usb or what? Thank you sir